# Add element to website/tab from Safari extension

Tags: javascript, safari, element, safari-extension

I am trying to create an extension for Safari that will add an element to the page/tab that I am currently on. In the example below I'd like to add the Send button to the page.

The issue for me is that the new element (button) will be added to the extensions html.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function sendMessage() {
        document.getElementById("textField").innerHTML="Sending message...";
        safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.page.dispatchMessage("hey", "there");
    }

    function respondToMessage(messageEvent) {
        if(messageEvent.name === "gotIt")
        document.getElementById("textField").innerHTML=messageEvent.message;
    }

    safari.self.browserWindow.addEventListener("message",respondToMessage,false);

</script>
</head>
<body> Message Sender Bar &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="sendMessage()" >
    <span id="textField">...waiting... </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Js:

```
var theBody = document.body;
var element = document.createElement("p");
element.id = "status";
element.style.cssText = "float:right; color:red";
element.textContent = "Waiting...";
theBody.insertBefore(element, theBody.firstChild);

function replyToMessage(aMessageEvent) {
   if (aMessageEvent.name === "hey") {
    document.getElementById("status").textContent="Message received.";
    safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("gotIt","Message acknowledged.");
    }
}
safari.self.addEventListener("message", replyToMessage, false);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your issue is?  It's not clear why "the new element will be added to the extensions html" is a problem.

Comment: Have you [followed these instructions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/injecting_a_script_into_a_webpage) and injected your HTML-modifying script into the webpage?

Comment: @Jim B I was just curious how I could do it, since I wasn't sure and I am very novice. :)

Thanks to the both of you, I was able to do it by specifying the host with window.location.host and a config for the website.